# cant pass array as a parameter in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp

I have forgotten how to pass an array as a parameter in cakephp3 to a function in a controller as below. The array $sIds has values but i cant pass this to the function below.

```
//conroller function

   // return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'viewguardians',array($sIds)));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'viewguardians',$sIds));
}


public function viewguardians($sIds=[])
{
            foreach ($sIds as  $item):
                debug($item);
            endforeach;   
}
```

Comment: I found the answer to my question after posting. I thought i would post the answer but I could have just deleted the question. Either way getting a lot of down votes seems mean spirited

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, as i need to serialize to pass and unserialize the array to view.

This works so I answered my own question which shouldnt be losing votes as I could have just deleted it.

```
 $a=serialize($sIds);
  return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'viewguardians',$a));
..
}


   public function viewguardians($a=null)
{

   $stIds=array();

    $stIds=unserialize($a);
```